# How to utilize GUI tool of pgadmin using vagrant

Tags: postgresql, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I have installed postgresql upon a vagrant ubuntu box and also companied control console with

```
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install pgadmin3
```

the tool is installed under /usr/bin

but I can not open pdadmin3 in the virtualbox due to the error

```
Error: Unable to initialize gtk, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

Could I possibly do this kind of thing in vagrant virtual box ? Or some work around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run PgAdmin locally on your main desktop and connect to PostgreSQL on your Vagrant VM over TCP/IP.

The host can connect to guests if properly configured. You'll need to (a) ensure that Vagrant has suitable networking from host to guest, either using NAT and port forwards or using a virtual bridge; (b) ensure that PostgreSQL on the guest listens on all interfaces for TCP/IP connections using `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf` and (c) ensure that PostgreSQL on the guest is configured to allow connections from remote peers in `pg_hba.conf`.

Alternately, PgAdmin supports ssh tunnels. If you can ssh to the virtualbox you can configure PgAdmin to ssh to it too, then make a local PostgreSQL connection.

Personally I prefer to instead just use the `psql` command-line client for PostgreSQL directly on the VM. Way less hassle.